# NodeJS modules context

Tags: node.js

I've installed **globally** the **express** module and is localised in

```
D:\Programs\nodejs\npm\node_modules\express
```

Now If I want to use this module I need to write this in my .js file

```
var express = require("D:\Programs\nodejs\npm\node_modules\express");
```

What to do to write it this way

```
var express = require("express");
```

Because now this **works**: `require("http");`, but this: **doesn't** `require("express");`

Answer (score -1):

Try to install express using

`npm install express`.

Then you will able to access it like

```
require('express');
```

Above command install `express` module in your local `node_module` of app.